# iPhone SE: USB sound input -> bluetooth speaker?

Tags: iphone, audio, usb, bluetooth

I would like to hear the output from my old turntable in my bluetooth speaker through an iPhone or iPad.  I need help on how to get it working.

I have an iPhone SE, a bluetooth speaker which is paired with the iPhone (music works), a [UFO202 USB RIAA amplifier](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Audio-Interfaces/UFO202/p/P0A12) connected with a newly purchased Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter (to have enough power for the USB device and also keep the phone charged)

I can hear the audio when the UFO202 is attached to my MacBook Pro (and transmit it if the Mac is paired with the speaker).

I installed Garageband on the iPhone and the UFO202 appears to be recognized as Garageband send modified sound back into the UFO202 (which I can hear in the headphone jack there).  This did not appear to send anything over bluetooth but I am not familiar with Garageband.

So the only piece missing is how I can make the iPhone take the USB input sound and send to the bluetooth speaker?  Can Garageband do it?  Memos?  Do I need a third part app?

Comment: I haven't gathered enough information to write a proper answer, but you may need to buy up to three third party apps, one of which will be Audiobus http://audiob.us which does the routing between the other two apps.

Comment: Possible Apple support article:  https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24782?locale=en_US

Comment: I try to do something similar (use an iPhone 4S as a bridge between my record player and Airplay) and wonder how you get stereo sound into your iPhone SE? Does the camera adapter support that??

Comment: I can add a datapoint. I have the camera adapter and use it with my iPhone SE and iPad Mini 3 and stream music to Airplay devices using Garageband. If Airplay works one would think Bluetooth should be fine too.

Answer (score 3):

[Audiobus](https://audiob.us/) v3 has been launched and this *may* be all you need.

The app already supports Garageband (along with hundreds of others) and they provide an SDK (software development kit) for other app developers. This too has been updated to support new functionality included in version 3.

**What I do know**

- I know of someone who owns the Behringer UCA202 (not the Behringer UFO202) and has used that to route incoming audio from a guitar via a **genuine** Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter to an iPad 4 and then outputting that audio via GarageBand using the [Audiobus](https://audiob.us/) app.
- While it's not the same Behringer unit as you have, my understanding is that the only real difference is that the Behringer UFO202 you have foregoes the digital stereo out to provide a switchable PHONO input for old turntables such as yours.
- Also, I remember them having issues at first until they used a **genuine** Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter. They couldn't get it to work with a cheaper 3rd party adapter.

**What I don't know**

- Whether this person has ever used this process to route the audio from the iPad to an external Bluetooth speaker. This is something I will try to determine.
- The only other thing I'm not 100% certain of is whether they used anything else to get this to work, but from memory it was just a combination of the Behringer UCA202, a **genuine** Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter, the [Audiobus](https://audiob.us/) app and GarageBand.

If that's the case, then you *should* find that what you want to do is possible with [Audiobus](https://audiob.us/) and GarageBand.

**[Update]**

Okay, this is what I've since learnt after originally posting this answer.

As I mentioned previously, I know of someone who owns a Behringer UCA202. Now, it seems they did try for a little while to route music to a Bluetooth speaker, but with mixed (mainly not good) results. They tried doing this via Audiobus directly and in conjunction with other apps.

This prompted direct contact with Audiobus support and below is a quote from the support email they got back:

> Sorry, Audiobus does not play well with Bluetooth speakers. I cannot
>   recommend using Audiobus for this use case. Bluetooth audio is always
>   terrible for live audio, because it adds latency. That’s why we’re not
>   supporting it. Any wired speaker will do - they don’t have any issues.

As routing music wasn't their main use case (they were mainly interested in recording guitars), they didn't pursue it. However, if I was in your shoes, it *may* be worth trying Audiobus in conjunction with a 3.5mm to Bluetooth transmitter. I'd wait for Audiobus 3 to be released first, and then I'd look at transmitters such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P24XKS8). (Note: This is just one I picked at random - I have no affiliation with the seller or product).

My thinking is that Audiobus will see something like this as a *wired* speaker and that this could result in you achieving what you want.

Obviously, only you can decide whether the costs of buying the app and transmitter are worth the expense, especially since it's purely to experiment with and with no guarantee of success.

Hopefully someone else will come up with a confirmed solution, but if not this may be it. All the best with it.

Comment: My "Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter" is genuine.  I am certain the UFO202 is detected by the iPhone.

Comment: Just letting you know I haven't forgotten about this. I expect to hear back today (or _maybe_ tomorrow), so will be able to update my answer with more info then.

Comment: Now some time later there has been a few iOS updates and I came back to this.  The new Airplay2 stuff may make things feasible, otherwise I will look into the small bluetooth adapter.