# Can iOS-devices take sound in and send to Airplay?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, airplay, recording

I plan to find an old iPhone to make my record player connect to Airplay. Is that possible?

What I want to do is to take stereo line signal and "input" it into the phone and then playback it on the phone to an Apple TV. Is that possible? What hardware do I need to get the stereo signal into the phone and what software would allow me to redirect the in-signal to Airplay?

Comment: You may find this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/276541/168832) useful (although not a duplicate).

Comment: That actually solved part of my problem in an unexpected way. Now I "just" need something that allows my phone to receive a stereo signal via its 30-pin connector. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [solution](http://davidbo.livejournal.com/795.html). It is described in detail below.

**What you need**

- a RIAA preamp with USB Audio output, such as a [Behringer UFO202](http://amzn.to/2sutBIu)
- Apple's [Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter](https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4974/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/K0/MK0W2/MK0W2?wid=1144&hei=1144&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5%2C0.5%2C0%2C0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1479496994382)
- an iOS device with [GarageBand](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/garageband/id408709785?mt=8) installed

**The steps you need to follow**

1. Connect your record player to the RIAA preamp
2. Connect the RIAA preamp to the camera adapter.
3. Connect a Lightning USB cable to the camera adapter (unless you want to run this on battery power).
4. In GarageBand (on your iOS device), select Audio Recorder as the instrument (see screenshot below taken from an iPad):

[image]

5. Turn on monitoring

[image]

6. Select *Stereo* as the Channel and enable the Monitor option (see screenshot below)

[image]

7. OPTIONAL: It may be a good idea to increase the Out volume (use the vertical slider on the right)

[image]

8. Switch on your record player
9. Set your iOS device to use Airplay speakers for sound playback

Now, everytime you want to use your record player you can just connect your iOS device to the RIAA preamp and it'll become an input selector.

**NOTE:** If you get a warning about delays and latency you can just dismiss it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73622/discussion-on-answer-by-d-b-can-ios-devices-take-sound-in-and-send-to-airplay).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer of @d-b did not work for my setup. I was not able to choose HomePod the Step 9. However my setup is a bit different so that may explain why.

David Rosnow's answered however worked, but I would like to share the full setup I used:

- A TV with a RCA output as the source.
- A RCA to mini-jack cable
- A TRS to TTRS converter (SC-4 from Rhode)
- The Apple Mini Jack to Lightning adpapter from
- An iPhone mini 12
- A pair of HomePod mini and a single HomePod mini
- AirChord App (https://www.airchordapp.com) or Microphone Live

With this setup, everything works but with some limitations : I cannot play both my HomePod mini pair and the single HomePod, I need to choose the pair OR the single one. Also, with this setup I cannot sync the image and the sound. But if you accept these limitations that setup worked well.

Answer (score 0):

There's also this app now that does a lot of this with one step.

https://www.airchordapp.com